# Draw a progress that grows

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, progress-bar

In the following code, I want to draw a progress bar that grows. what should I call at the line marked

```
// what goes here?
```

Assume the code is run on the main thread.

```
class View: UIView {
    func updateProgressBar(){

        var boxFrame = CGRect(x:10, y:10: width:100, height: 100)

        for _ in 0...<10 {

            let box = UIView(frame: boxFrame)
            box.backgroundColor = .blue
            addSubview(box)

            // What goes here?

            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
            boxFrame.origin.x = boxFrame.width
        }
    }
}
```

What will be the answer from the following option and why?

1. setNeedsDisplay()
2. layer.draw(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentConntext()!)
3. draw(bounds)
4. This approach is incorrect. It should be implemented in another way. such as with *DispatchQueue.asyncAfter()*

Comment: You can use UIProgressView If your intent is to display a network request.

Comment: @LeoDabus I didn't get your answer. I have asked what will be the possible answer from those options and why.

Comment: It is not an answer it is a comment. Your question is unclear. If you want to display time progress you need to use a timer.

Comment: Still unclear what is your goal? Are you trying to display your network dataTask progress ?

Comment: @LeoDabus no data task will be called.  My goal is to make this  _updateProgressBar()_ method functional.  And to make it functional which method from the provided options I need to call after the comment  _// What goes here?_ .